# Using an Alternative maven repo when artifact isn't resolved

Tags: java, maven, repository, nexus

So i recently started with maven and i have made 2 private nexus repos one that listens on 8081 and the other on 8083, and on each repo i have different dependencies.

I want to configure maven from the settings so that it works with the first repo (8081), but when it can't find a dependecy on it it will switch to the other (8083) but only for that dependecy, then it completes with the default repo (8081), is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just configure your two repositories in the `settings.xml`.

Maven will always look first in the first one, and if it did not find the dependency, it will look in the second one.

Since your repos (hopefully!) don't overlap, there is little to worry about.